# How could I construct a binary tree parallelly

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, tree

I want to use a binary tree(actually, VP Tree) to implement my search algorithm. I need to first use the input points to construct the tree and then do one query for every input point.

in the single thread version, the bottleneck is in the search procedure, however, after some optimization, the search procedure could get satisfying speedup on multi-core platforms, so the bottleneck changed to the construction part.

during constrution, I need to first partition all points into two parts, and then build the left subtree and the right subtree recursively. when doing partition , I use in place method to rearrange the input array. so I think there might be some `false sharing`.

I tried to accelerate the construction using c++11 `std::thread`. that is, use an `std::atomic<int>` as a thread counter, and when I need to build two subtrees and the total threads are less than the max thread limit I have set, then I spawn one another thread for the left subtree. the branching part is like below

However, the method above doesn't scale on multi-core platforms, for example, on my 80-core, 160-thread platform, the `search` procedure get 100x speedup, while the construction only get 4x speedup and the speed up for whole program reduced to about 30x.

so, generally, what technique could I utilize to construct a binary tree efficiently?

Here is a simplified version of the construction code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>
using std::thread;
using namespace std::chrono;
std::default_random_engine g(0);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distr(0, 100);
class Tree
{
public:
    struct Node
    {
        int idx; // index of point
        double threshold;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };
    Tree(double* points, size_t size, int maxThread)
        : _nodes(new Node[size]),
          _items(points), // order does not matter, and won't modify value
          _size(size),
          _maxThread(maxThread),
          _currentThread(1)
    {
        buildFromPoints(0, 0, size);
        _currentThread = 1;
    }
private:
    Node*     _nodes;
    double*   _items;
    const int _size;
    const int _maxThread;
    std::atomic<int> _currentThread;

    void buildFromPoints(int nodeIdx, int lower, int upper)
    {
        // build from [lower,upper) of _items
        // would rearrange elements in the above range
        if (lower >= upper)
            return;
        auto& node     = _nodes[nodeIdx];
        node.idx       = lower;
        node.left      = nullptr;
        node.right     = nullptr;
        node.threshold = 0;
        if (upper - lower > 1) // at least two elements
        {
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(lower, upper - 1);
            int pivotIdx = distr(g);
            std::swap(_items[lower], _items[pivotIdx]);
            int median = (upper + lower - 1) / 2;
            auto cmp = [&](const double p1, const double p2)->bool
            {
                return fabs(p1 - _items[lower]) < fabs(p2 - _items[lower]);
            };
            std::nth_element(
                    _items + lower + 1,
                    _items + median,
                    _items + upper,
                    cmp);
            node.threshold = fabs(_items[lower] - _items[median]);
            int nodeSize = nodeIdx + 1;
            if(lower < median)
                node.left = _nodes + nodeSize;
            if(median + 1 < upper)
                node.right = _nodes + nodeSize + median - lower;
            if(node.left && node.right)
            {                
                if (_maxThread > _currentThread)
                {
                    ++_currentThread;
                    std::thread t1(
                            &Tree::buildFromPoints,
                            this,
                            nodeSize,
                            lower + 1,
                            median + 1);
                    buildFromPoints(nodeSize + median - lower, median + 1, upper);
                    t1.join();
                }
                else
                {
                    buildFromPoints(nodeSize, lower + 1, median + 1);
                    buildFromPoints(nodeSize + median - lower, median + 1, upper);
                }
            }
            else if (node.left)
                buildFromPoints(nodeSize, lower + 1, median + 1);
            else if (node.right)
                buildFromPoints(nodeSize + median - lower, median + 1, upper);
        }
    }
};
int main(int argNum, char** args)
{
    int pointsNum = 10;
    int threadNum = 1;
    if(argNum > 1)
        pointsNum = atoi(args[1]);
    if(argNum > 2)
        threadNum = atoi(args[2]);
    double* arr = new double[pointsNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsNum; i++)
        arr[i] = distr(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("arr[%d] = %g\n", i, arr[i]);
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    Tree t(arr,pointsNum,threadNum);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double timeSpan = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1).count();
    printf("time used: %g s\n",timeSpan);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Threads are expensive resource (syscall to create it, bookkeeping of OS structures, allocation of thread stack) and thus frequent creation/destruction may cause significant overhead to your code. I would suggest trying your implementation (left and right subtrees in parallel) however using thread pool to distribute the work.

Comment: How do you obtain your "Input points". Usually building a tree from input is i/o-bound and the tree bulding insignificant. Do provide a complete but minimal example that readers in principle could try out.

Comment: What is the 80-core system?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Intel E7 8850, ten CPUs, each has 10 core, 20 threads.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have added a example, you could try and compile it, I would very appreciate if you would like to help.

Comment: Not sure if I have time, but just a small observation: you can easily overshoot your max number of threads via `if (_maxThread > _currentThread)`. I would think you can't get more than double the number of threads, though.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes, that's a little bug...